# Hi all! I have a problem installing modules nest.js

Tags: nestjs

I just started learning nest.js. and immediately ran into a problem. First, I initialize the project with the command: npm i -g @nestjs/cli. After nest new project-name. To which I get an error in the terminal: the nest command was not found. In the terminal, the command npm list -g @nestjs/cli shows @nestjs/cli@10.1.8

How can I fix this error?

node.js version: v16.20.0
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/nest/bin"

Comment: It looks like your npm global install location is not in your path. You can use `npm config get prefix` to see what the path to that directory is